# Why does my Promise return a database row in some cases but not in others?

Tags: node.js, promise, node-postgres

I have a function in a module `db` that uses node-postgres to insert a new row into a database:

```
module.exports={addUser: function(phonenumber){
        return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
            queryStr='insert into users (phonenumber,status,exitStatus) values (\''+phonenumber+'\') returning *';
            pool.query(queryStr,(err,res)=>{
                if (err){
                    reject(err);
                }
                else{
                    resolve(res);
                }
            });
        });

    }
}
```

When I call it like this:

```
var number=123456789;
testAddUser(number);

function testAddUser(phonenumber){
    db.addUser(phonenumber).then(val=>{console.log(val.rows[0])});
}
```

Then it successfully outputs the returned row to the console log:

```
anonymous {
  id: 25,
  phonenumber: '123456789'}
```

Which is what I want.

But when I call it like this, from within another Promise-returning function's `then`:

```
db.someOther_promise(num).then(value=>{
            doSomeStuff();
            return db.addUser(num);
    }).then(value=>{
        console.log("value "+value.rows[0]);
    })
```

Then I only get the output:

```
value [object Object]
```

That makes me wonder if maybe `someOther_promise()` is completing and starting the `.then()` resolution before the `db.addUser(num)` call completes.  But I thought that returning a promise means that the second `.then()` has to wait for the promise created by the return value of the first `.then()` to complete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that this has nothing to do with Promises. When you do

```
console.log("value "+value.rows[0]);
```

you are converting `value.rows[0]` to string which then outputs `value [object Object]`. If you use `console.log("value ", value.rows[0])` instead, you should see the desired output...